# Best way to create sub cases from closed cases

Tags: case, queue

We are trying to put a process in place that assigns a CLOSED case to a queue for an audit review based on the risk score of the case.  So I need all cases with a risk score of 1 or 2 to be sent to the QA queue automatically after the case is closed.

I tried creating workflow to do this, but then I lose my closed case date/time information.  I know the possibility to create a parent/child case hierarchy exists, but I need a push in the right direction on how to automatically (without CSR having to push a button) have a "new" case created with many of the same details and sent to the QA queue for review.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Can you historize the dated activities on the case and introduce REVIEW status?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a new Case, it's a poor decision from a data architecture perspective IMO.

I would create multiple 'Closed' case status values. So the CSR sets the case to Closed1, at which point a workflow reassigns the Case to the QA team. Once review is completed, the QA agent sets the case status to Closed2.

Comment: I like the idea and thought about that, but the person reviewing the case has up to 60 days to complete the review.  So if they change the status from Closed 1 to Closed 2, it will change the Date/Time Closed and we will lose the actual timestamp right?

Comment: I'm not sure if closing the status from one 'Closed' status to another will update the Closed timestamp - worth testing.

Comment: i bet @brich1975 would totally upvote this answer if DavinC upvoted the question :D :D